# One person using multiple characters in separate campaigns who will be at war

Tags: problem-players, metagaming, player-vs-player

In our game, we have a good campaign and an evil campaign. Our DM has us going separate games until the ending battle.

We have a player who has decided to have a character in each campaign. Cool, no problem. Problem is, he seems to be under the impression that he can use any knowledge gained by either character to benefit him in either campaign (knowledge gained from evil used in good against evil. Knowledge from good used in evil against good).

He has stated multiple times that he will only stay with the winning side, which he then feels he should be able to take all information gained from the other campaign with him to use against them.

Should this be allowed in the game? Our DM doesn't know what this player's plans are yet. We want to build a case to get him kicked. But I want to know if it goes against the rules or not. Should be common sense though.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Don't forget to take the [tour]! You have not mentioned which system you are playing. The way this is usually done is by adding the corresponding tag to the question. I hope we can be of help with your issue.

Comment: To what extent does he uses the knowledge of one to benefit him in the other ? Would it be comparable to a player preemptively reading the module that he's about to partake in ?

Comment: I'm closing this since ultimately it's your game and your rules -- various people can tell you what they *think* the rules should be, but there are no universal rules about whether people can or can't do that stuff.

Comment: A rephrase of the question might get it back open.  Focus on what is actually concerning you.  The fact that this player is using his player knowledge to get an edge on the other players in the group.  Effectively a bit of spotlight hogging.  This is not going to be a game rules issue. it is a group cohesion issue.

Comment: I had mostly wanted to see if it was a game rules issue. Our DM has decided that he's not going to be using two characters. Nor is he on our side anymore after going agro on me for something that happened in game.

Answer (score -2):

Players should always respect the difference and relationship between player and character knowledge. If there are repeated examples of the player cheating by using information in one game to benefit him in the other, there should be penalty. However, it could be argued that it goes against the spirit of the game to kick someone out, though it is not specifically against the rules. Present your case to the DM. It should be their discretion as to what is done about this player.